# How do I convert a database record into a string in Visual Basic?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010

I tried using :
Topic = QuizData.Tables("Results").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
but it only returned a number. I am planning to output the string into a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need to retrieve data into dataset variable which is filled by using adaptor.

```
adaptor.Fill(dataset, "0")
String Topic = dataset.Tables("Results").Rows(0).Item(0).ToString();
```

Hope this will be help to you :) if you want more clarifications just inform.